# Connect to SQL instance to get version with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have to check if an SQL Server is installed on random computers (running code locally) and connect to the instance and find the version of the SQL Server. Is this possible without having logins?

I've been told not to use the registry to look for the information and instead been suggested a couple of methods that both require connection with the instance. This of course will require the SQL Server to be running.

For extra info, I need to run either `@@version` or `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`

I'd assume I need to at least use Windows Authentication, but will that be possible? These are computers that run in a production environment and I have "no control" over them (except that I can run my code on everyone of them).

Comment: You don't necessarily need Windows Authentication - and indeed, it is possible that a given server **will not let you** (i.e. it could be sql auth only). What you would need would be: a valid connection string, and a valid identity (whether that is sql auth or windows auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask the SQL Server instance a question you need to connect to it! And in order to do that you need a valid (Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication) connection-string - so someone needs to provider you with that!